# Refer to an output parameter in aws IAM policy cloud formation document

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloud formation template that needs to build a IAM policy based on the output variable of other cloud formation. The Resource part corresponding to the policy is the one bellow.

The issue is the Fn::ImportValue in the Condition but also in the Resource sections, when I got an error that Fn:ImportedValue is not a string.

Therefore, my question is how can I refer from Resource or Condition section to an output from a different cloud formation?

Thanks,
 Florin

```
{
"LambdaPolicy": {
            "DependsOn": [
                "LambdaRole"
            ],
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
            "Properties": {
                "PolicyName": {
                    "Ref": "FunctionName"
                },
                "Roles": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "LambdaRole"
                    }
                ],
                "PolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": [
                                "logs:*"
                            ],
                            "Resource": [
                                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "Sid": "AllowAccesToDL",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": [
                                "s3:*"
                            ],
                            "Resource": "*",
                            "Condition": {
                                "ArnLike": {
                                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                        {
                                            "Fn::ImportValue": [
                                                {
                                                    "Fn::Join": [
                                                        "-",
                                                        [
                                                            {
                                                                "Ref": "BasisStackName"
                                                            },
                                                            "OutputBucketNameFromOtherBucket"
                                                        ]
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "Arn"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Ref` intrinsic works within the same CloudFormation stack. It won't work against an independent stack that you created earlier.

You could declare the resource (S3 bucket?) name as an input parameter to the 2nd template and then provide the bucket name manually when you create the 2nd stack.